# Website size decreases while converting to WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, web

I am converting an HTML site to WordPress, and it's done. Now it seems like the total size is reduced, but the units are correct (same as the original HTML, i.e. 980px width etc.).

Please help me with that.

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title><?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
</head>
```

Comment: What "size" do you mean? Number of bytes per page load? It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Check your styles once again. May be other styles may contradict with the width. Could you please provide more information excatly?

Comment: im running locally. so i cant provide you link. i copied the stylesheet and replaced with twentyten theme. editted header, footer, index files.. just that... and now the whole site size is reduced..

Comment: I have added the head tag in the question. i removed wp_head functions and all.. to avoid those kind of issues.

Comment: If you are trying to modify the twentyten theme to have your custom theme, then its not the best way to do it. You may need to go through these books http://www.amazon.com/WordPress-Theme-Design-complete-professional/dp/1847193099

Comment: Have you added the firebug extension for your browser? If not, i suggest you add it and use it. Its useful to inspect your html elements and their styles.

Comment: i have firebug. i can see all the measurements are correct.. but the size changed, will there be any issees with the doc type.. that is also copied from the html

Comment: Refresh the cache of the browser once and check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, more info would be helpful. The chances are good WP is linking to another stylsheet you don't know about. Are you using a theme? It's probably got it's own stylesheet, or another plugin is adding it's own style.